# Rails Rest-Post Params hash not written

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, hash

I m building my first REST API using Rails and have a simple question which  I am unable  to solve.

Basically i am not able to write a params hash into the database from a http `PUSH` request.

I have the following user controller under the Api namespace  with  the create action.

```
class Api::UserController < ApplicationController
      http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "test", :password => "test"
      skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

      def create
             @user = User.create(params[:user])
              respond_to do |format|
                      if @user.save
                              format.json{render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user} #render create full response
                      else
                              format.json{render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
                      end
              end
      end
end
```

The route to this action is

```
 POST    /api/user(.:format)    api/user#create{:format=>"json"}
```

The user model has a name and a address string not contained.

To test the REST call i  setup  the firefox plugins `RESTeasy` and `RESTclient`
with this URL  `http://localhost:3000/api/user/`

and  this  body 
    {
        "name": "timoteo",
        "address": "berlin"
    }

So far so good. Now after sending this package  Webrick  gives me this output:

```
Started POST "/api/user" for ::1 at 2015-08-03 17:06:50 +0200
Processing by Api::UserController#create as JSON
 Parameters: {"name"=>"timoteo", "address"=>"berlin"}
  (1.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2015-08-03 15:06:50.646169"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-03 15:06:50.646169"]]
  (42.8ms)  COMMIT
  (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  (0.3ms)  COMMIT
 Completed 201 Created in 66ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 48.1ms)
```

neglecting the two parameter and  an empty  empty record like this one gets stored in the database(also the REST clients show me the same)

```
{"id":19,"name":null,"address":null,"created_at":"2015-08-03T15:06:50.646Z","updated_at":"2015-08-03T15:06:50.646Z"}
```

Can someone give me a hint what might have gone wrong during the way. I assume it is something with the params hash but i could not figure it out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add validation to your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_presence_of :name
   validates_presence_of :address
end
```

That will disallow saving record with blank attributes.

Then, change your `#save` call to `#persisted?` in your controller (because record is created immediately after `#create` is called, it is already saved or failed)

```
if @user.persisted?
  format.json{render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user} #render create full response
else
  format.json{render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
end
```

**UPD**. You could also benefit from whitelisting parameters which you accept:

```
@user = User.create(params.require(:name, :address))
```

This way Rails will respond with error, saying parameter is missing, and will not assign any other attributes to user (which you don't want to be assigned).

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer. I have some validation but excluded it to make the model more simple. With validate_presence_of :name  and changing save to persisted i am not able to write anymore. RESTclient gives me back this json msg {"name": [ "can't be blank"]} . The INSERT operation looks the same as before

Comment: Please give the line from the logs where parameters are shown (`Parameters: { ... }`)

Comment: Oh, I see it in your original answer. Seems like you need to fix your params hash like the other responder suggested ({user: {name: ..., address: ...}), then it's gotta be fine. Try restarting the server.

Comment: Ok the List is the following Parameters: {"name"=>"timoteo", "address"=>"berlin"} When i neglect the body and use this URL http://localhost:3000/api/customer?name=timoteo&address=berlin it give the same result. So i think it is not the Clients

Comment: Yeah, you need either to change your params, or change `params[:user]` to `params.permit(:name, :address)`

Comment: This is the Parameter List i get when i use this  json body { "user": { "name": "timoteo", "address": "berlin" } }       Parameters: {"{ \"user\": { \"name\": \"timoteo\", \"address\": \"berlin\" } }"=>nil}

Comment: I edited my answer. Change the code to use `params.require` as I suggested and then do `curl -XPOST  localhost:3000/api/customer?name=timoteo&address=berlin` (or just do request without body in your client).

Answer (score 1):

Your params of `{ "name": "timoteo", "address": "berlin" }` are incorrect when your user creation is `@user = User.create(params[:user])`

You params should look more like:`{ "user": { "name": "timoteo", "address": "berlin" } }` because you're accessing `params[:user]` so the user attributes need to belong to the user section of your params.

Adding Validations may help if its incorrect to save a User with no name/address too.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :address, presence: true
  # etc...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think i understand now the relation between hash name and the params send. I tried the hash you suggested, i also included the validation but the result is the same.  Started POST "/api/user/" for ::1 at 2015-08-03 17:58:18 +0200
Processing by Api::UserController#create as JSON
   (2.0ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity

Comment: What are the parameters in your log showing when you make that request?

Comment: This is the params list from the log Parameters: {"{{ \"name\": \"timoteo\", \"address\": \"berlin\" } }"=>nil}
Unpermitted parameters: {{ "name": "timoteo", "address": "berlin" } }, format
I changed now params[:user] to params.permit(:name :address)